# How can I call an async method inside an anonymous delegate?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a function takes a delegate as input parameter.

```
public delegate bool Callback();

public static class MyAPI
{
     public static handle(Callback callback) {
           ... 
     }
}
```

So I call the api with an anonymous delegate like this

```
MyAPI.handle(delegate
{
    // my implementation
});
```

My question is how can i call an async method in my anonymous delegate?

```
MyAPI.handle(delegate
{
    // my implementation
    await MyMethodAsync(...);
});
```

I get an error saying the 'await' operator can only be used within async anonymous method'?

The function MyAPI.handle() only expect a non async delegate. I can't change that method. How can I fix my problem?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't... If you clarify whether you need result of the method or just fire-and-forget one can find good duplicate showing appropriate dirty hacks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could call an asynchronous method by passing an async lambda expression:

```
MyAPI.handle(async () =>
{
    // my implementation
    await MyMethodAsync(...);
});
```

Comment: While you can use `async` with lambda expressions, you can also use them with anonymous methods (use `async delegate`). In OP's scenario either will generate a compiler error since the delegate type Callback does not return void, Task, or Task<T>.

Comment: @mikez not to sound like that Guy, but in your comment you mention lambda expressions and anonymous methods as if there are two different entities. While in fact a lambda expression is an anonymous method. What  I think you meant to say was you can either use an anonymous method via a lamda expression or you can use a delegate.

Comment: @KING I guess I will be the pedantic one and say formally the spec defines *anonymous functions* as the umbrella term for inline method declarations. Anonymous functions can come in two forms, *anonymous methods* and *lambda expressions*. To quote the spec: "For historical reasons there are two syntactic flavors of anonymous functions, namely lambda-expressions and anonymous-method-expressions. For almost all purposes, lambda-expressions are more concise and expressive than anonymous-method-expressions, which remain in the language for backwards compatibility.".

Comment: @KING If you peruse the spec you will notice it is very careful with this usage and it uses "anonymous method" solely to refer to the delegate form, however in casual conversation they are used interchangeably.

Answer (score 2):

```
MyAPI.handle(async () =>
{
    // my implementation
    await MyMethodAsync(...);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for people like me that don't really like how lambdas look.

```
MyAPI.handle(
    async delegate() {
        // my implementation
        await MyMethodAsync(...);
    }
);
```